# Generate AlphaNumeric Sequence in Oracle PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql

Hi guys I want to create a sequence for an unique primary key, it should starts in 0000 and increment 1 by 1, e.g 0001, 0002. When numeric chars finish at 9, next value should be 000A and next one 000B to 000Z, then next one should be 0010 (0011, 0012 and so on). I'm really new to oracle and I don't really understand how to do this, can anyone give me a light? thank you!

Comment: why does it have to be alphanumeric?  If the sequence value is just to provide a PK, then just use a plain-old-sequence object,  and call nextval on it.  Rolling your own sequence has its own  problems, such as concurrent access/generation from multiple sessions.  I don't think you need to do what you are requesting.

Comment: have a look at this: https://community.oracle.com/thread/3926021?start=15&tstart=0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got this:

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION GENERA_ALFANUM (N INTEGER) RETURN VARCHAR2
     IS
      Q INTEGER;
      R VARCHAR2(4);
    BEGIN
      Q := N;
      WHILE Q >= 36 LOOP
         R := CHR(MOD(Q,36)+CASE WHEN MOD(Q,36) < 10 THEN 48 ELSE 55 END) || R;
         Q := FLOOR(Q/36);
      END LOOP;
      R := CHR(MOD(Q,36)+CASE WHEN MOD(Q,36) < 10 THEN 48 ELSE 55 END) || R;
      RETURN LPAD(R,4,'0');
    END;
```